# Check Function without execute it

Tags: php, model-view-controller, repository-pattern

i'm training SOLID/Architectures and trying to make an INSERT on my code, but its insert four times on DB. There's any error on my logic? I'm following Repositories/Service Pattern.

i think my service is executing two times, but i cant find the reason.

Repositorie Code

```
    public function inserirEstoque($dadosPost)
    {

        if (empty($dadosPost)) {
            return false;
        } 
        
        $pdo = $this->dbConnection->conectar();
        $sql = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO estoque (nomeProduto, descriptions, price, quantity)
                                 VALUES (:nome, :descriptions, :price, :quantity)');
        $sql->bindValue(':nome', $dadosPost['nomeProduto']);
        $sql->bindValue(':descriptions', $dadosPost['descriptions']);
        $sql->bindValue(':price', $dadosPost['price']);
        $sql->bindValue(':quantity', $dadosPost['quantity']);

        $res = $sql->execute();

        if($res == false)
        {
            return false;
        } 

        return $res;
    }
```

Service

```
public function insertEstoque()
    {
        
        $db = new MySQL();
        $insert = new EstoqueRepositories($db);

    
        if(!empty($insert->inserirEstoque($_POST))){
            return $insert->inserirEstoque($_POST);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
  public function insert()
    {
         $insert = new EstoqueService();
         $insert->insertEstoque();
         header('Location: ../../index.php');
    }
```

Comment: Yeah! It's an addiction which i have to fix, thanks for the alert!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an addition to Reed's answer, if you just want to check the result of a function call before carrying on, assign the result to a variable and use that variable.

```php
$res = $insert->inserirEstoque($_POST)
if(!empty($res)){
  return $res;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: It solved my problem, but personally i dont know why. Whats the difference between the code i made and it?

Comment: The function you wrote inserts a row every time it is called, and you called it twice. It doesn't matter that you called it twice with the same arguments, it did exactly what you asked, just not what you wanted.

Comment: This took a little more logic than I expected. Many thanks to you and Reed for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It's executing twice because of this

```php
if(!empty($insert->inserirEstoque($_POST))){
  return $insert->inserirEstoque($_POST);
 } else {
  return false;
}
```

if you wanna check if the POST data is empty just remove where it inserts the data then it should just insert it 1 time

```
if(!empty($_POST["whatevername"])){
  return $insert->inserirEstoque($_POST);
 } else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Still happening. If i take the repository function direct by controller, it works, but i cant make a treatment following single-principle. This just insert two times, even using $_POST.

Comment: @Eder well twice is better than 4 times. So you've made progress. Now you should add some logging...possibly the request is being made twice to the PHP script somehow? And/or maybe `insert()` in the Controller is called twice? We can't see how that function is invoked.

Comment: @Eder Chances are you've repeated this same pattern of calling the function multiple times elsewhere in code that you've not posted. You should break this habit. While some code is idempotent, meaning it can be called repeatedly without side-effects, such code must be written carefully with idempotency in mind. Plus it is usually preferable to simply save the result of the first call and use that instead of repeatedly re-computing.

Comment: Thanks Reed and Sammitch! And i'll find better ways to improve it.